# How to start a marquee with JavaScript based on user input?

Tags: javascript, html, marquee

I am trying to use JavaScript to start a marquee when a user puts their name into a textbox and then clicks a button. I've got an idea as to how to do it, but my script never fully works. Any help is appreciated!

Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function StartMarquee() {
        var text = document.getElementById(namebox);
        if (text != null) {
            document.write("<marquee behavior='scroll' direction='right'>Hello " + text + "!</marquee>");
        }
        else {
            alert("Enter your name first!!!");
        }
    } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table style="margin:0px auto 0px auto;">
<tr><td>Enter your name!</td>
<td><input type="text" id="namebox"/></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="StartMarquee()"/></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "never fully works" mean?

Comment: Never fully works means that it either spits out an alert message saying "Enter your username first!" or it ahows a marquee that says "Hello null!".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JavaScript has a few problems.

1. You are passing an undefined variable `namebox` to `getElementById`. You need to put this in quotes (`'namebox'`).
2. You need to check the value of `text` against the empty string, not `null`.
3. You need to use the value of the input (`text.value` as opposed to just `text`) in the element you're creating.

Here is what your code would look like with these fixes:

```
function StartMarquee() {
  var text = document.getElementById('namebox');
  if (text.value !== '') {
    document.write("<marquee behavior='scroll' direction='right'>Hello " + text.value + "!</marquee>");
  }
  else {
    alert("Enter your name first!!!");
  }
}
```

Some other general suggestions:

1. Don't use `document.write`. Instead, use DOM methods to create a new element and insert it into the DOM.
2. Use unobtrusive JavaScript. Attach your behavior after the document loads instead of using inline event handlers.
3. Use `===` and `!==` for conditions to avoid type coercion and to ensure you're getting the result you think you are.
4. Never, ever use `marquee`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = document.getElementById(namebox).value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use `document.write` for this-- use `document.createElement('marquee')` to create the element, and then add it to the body of the page. You can set attributes like direction on the element you get back, and set its `innerHTML` to the text you want in the marquee.

(P.S. Marquee? Really?)

Comment: Yep really. Marquees aren't my favorite either, but I'm doing this for a competition with one of my friends.

Comment: @APShredder: competition. Good.

Answer (score 0):

use two html: one box in rather plain second html

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function StartMarquee() {
            var text = document.getElementById('namebox');
                if (text.value !== '') {
                        document.write("<marquee behavior='scroll' direction='left'>Hello " + text.value + "!/marquee>");
      }
                else {
                        alert("Enter your text first!!!");
      }
    } 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table style="margin:0px auto 0px auto;">
    <tr><td>your iframe embedded html must be the same as your device browser boxxed-html url thus requiring two html files!</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="namebox"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="StartMarquee()"/></td></tr>
    <style> html { background-color: green; text-align: center; color: white; font-family: Arial; }
    </style>
    </table>
    <style> table { background-color: green; text-align: center; color: white; font-family: Arial; }
    </style>
    </body>
    <style> body { background-color: green; text-align: center; color: white; font-family: Arial; }
    </style>
    </html>
    <style> html { background-color: green; text-align: center; color: white; font-family: Arial; }
    </style>
```

fits into next html code by iframe

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>TLDR-Text complete in marquee</title> 
     <style> body { background-color: green; text-align: center; color: white; font-family: Arial; }
     </style> 
    </head>
     <body> 
      <h1>Post Belowne
      </h1> 
      <iframe src="file:///C:/Users/Our%20Home/Documents/Purposting_boxtag.html" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="yes" frameborder="2" >
        <style> body { background-color: green; text-align: center; color: white; font-family: Arial; }
        </style>
    </iframe>
      <marquee> 
    ______________________________________________________________ </marquee> 
     </body>
    </html>
```

follow https://eniefiok.blogspot.com